# Heyacrazy: Fan-made edition

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is a Heyacrazy* puzzle. The rules are as follows:

- Shade in some cells in the grid. Two shaded cells cannot share an edge, and all unshaded cells must be orthogonally connected.
- Once finished, it is not possible to draw a line segment in the grid which passes through two borders (bolded lines) without passing through a shaded cell.

[image: Empty Heyacrazy grid]

[Penpa+ link](https://tinyurl.com/2jqw4b2g)

<sub>* Heyacrazy is a puzzle type created by Deusovi<sup>[[1]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87231/heyacrazy-crosses)</sup> based on Nikoli's [Heyawake](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/heyawake/).</sub>

Comment: Ha, I literally only just realised that the line segments in the centre of this puzzle spell out JAFE upside down! Slow moment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

> [image: Solution]

**Explanation:**

> The first step is to recognize that the v in the middle must be shaded in one of 2 ways, either
>   [image: Option 1]
>
>   or
>
>   [image: option 2].
>
>
>
>  However, if we progress down the first option, we will eventually reach this state:
>
>  [image: wrong path],
>
>  which would require us to shade 2 adjacent boxes to prevent any lines.
>
>  Thus, the correct start must thus be the second option.
>
>
>  From there we can fill out most of the grid via application of the rules until we reach this state:
>
>  [image: almost done]
>
>
>   Where we find this situation:
>
>   [image: final split]
>
>
>   One of the red or purple needs to be filled out, and one of the blue and purple needs to be filled out.
>
>
>   However, if we fill out the red and the blue, we will end up in this situation:
>
>   [image: wrong 2]
>
>
>   Where we can't fill in any of the red squares without breaking the continuous unshaded rule.
>
>
>   Thus, we must fill in the purple square, and from there the final few squares are straightforward, giving us a final state of:
>
>   [image: Solution]